# Passing more arguments to mapping functions in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, parameters, mapping

In LaTeX3, we may write these lines:

```
\cs_new_nopar:Nn \module_main:nn #1#2
  {
    \clist_map_function:NN \g_module_some_clist \module_mapping:n
  }  
\cs_new_nopar:Nn \module_mapping:n #1
  {
    % #1 is the clist item
  }
```

Now I also want to pass two arguments of `\module_main:nn` to `\module_mapping`. Are there any simple way to do this, except for defining two new functions similar to `\clist_map_function:NN` and `\__clist_map_function:Nw`?

To get full expansion I could not use `\clist_map_inline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard mapping functions are meant for the simple case where you want to pass the mapped tokens to some pre-defined auxiliary. In a non-expansion context you can define the auxiliary dynamically to include other data

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \module_main:N #1
  {
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \__module_aux:n ##1
      {
        % Code using #1
      }
    \clist_map_function:NN \l__module_clist \__module_aux:n
  }
```

or as you note use `\clist_map_inline:Nn`. The first approach can be used where the wrapper does not need to be expandable but the mapping does, while the second cannot.

For fully-expandable mappings the expectation is people will use the generic tools for defining recursions: it's not possible to predict every use case. For example, we might have

```
\cs_new:Npn \module_main:N #1
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__module_loop:Nw \exp_after:wN #1
      \l__module_clist , \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_loop:Nw #1#2 ,
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#2}
    % Code using #1 and #2
    \__module_loop:Nw #1 % Loop passing #1 from \module_main:N 
  }
```

Passing lots of arguments like this can get a be tricky and might require an auxiliary to do a 'shuffle' of the arguments, *e.g.*

```
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \module_main:Nnn 
  {
    \__module_aux:VNnn \l__module_clist
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_aux:nNnn #1#2#3#4
  {
      \__module_loop:Nnnw #2 {#3} {#4}
        #1 , \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__module_aux:nNnn { V }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_loop:Nnnw #1#2#3#4 ,
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#4}
    % Code using #1 to #4
    \__module_loop:Nnnw #1#2#3 % Loop passing args from \module_main:Nnn
  }
```

For cases where you want to do a test on the input and only use the other arguments in one case you leave the latter in the input stream and do something like

```
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \module_main:Nnn 
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__module_loop:wNnn
        \l__module_clist , \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_loop:wNnn #1 ,
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn {#1} ( \use_none:nnn }
    \str_if_eq:nnT {#1} { fixed-string }
      {
        \use_i_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:nw { \__module_aux:nNnn {#1} }
      }
    \__module_loop:wNnn
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_aux:nNnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    % Do stuff
  }
```

where `\use_i_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:nw` lets us break out of the loop and insert the auxiliary and the hit, while `\use_none:nnn` cleans up if there is no hit.

More generally, `\use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w`/`\use_i_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:nw` can be used to terminate a generic recursion prematurely irrespective of how many arguments are passed, so we might modify one of the above to

```
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \module_main:Nnn 
  {
    \__module_aux:VNnn \l__module_clist
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_aux:nNnn #1#2#3#4
  {
      \__module_loop:Nnnw #2 {#3} {#4}
        #1 , \q_recursion_tail , \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__module_aux:nNnn { V }
\cs_new:Npn \__module_loop:Nnnw #1#2#3#4 ,
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#4}
    \test:T % Terminate the loop early
      {
        \use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w
      }
    \__module_loop:Nnnw #1#2#3 % Loop passing args from \module_main:Nnn
  }
```

Comment: The same point applies to generic mappings to token lists, where multi-token relationships may be present in the data.

Comment: Is it a proper solution to this problem to create two new functions similar to `\clist_map_function:NN` and `\__clist_map_function:Nw`(Since I need \clist_map_break:)?

Comment: @Z.H. Please see the edit: the 'built in' functions are somewhat optimised but in general we can use the standard interfaces provided by `expl3` to create a range of recursion behaviours.

Comment: When reading the document for `\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do` function, I found it says `this is part of using \use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w`. Some mistakes in it?

Comment: @Z.H. Thanks.  Sorry I came across this much later.  The sentence was technically correct but confusing.  I've just reworded the documentation.